# Reconnect player in Game Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm having trouble figuring out how to reinvite a disconnected player in a good way, using the GKMatch class for the Game Center. The game is a 1 vs. 1 game.

When I detect a disconnected player, I try to reinvite that specific player to the match with this call:

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] addPlayersToMatch:theMatch matchRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
```

This works as it's supposed to do. When the other player has established the connection he gets reinvited and the match can continue. But this leaves a problem I haven't been able to solve. Here comes the scenario:

- Player 1 disconnects.
- Player 2 leaves the match while Player 1 is disconnected.
- Player 1 reconnects and detects that he lost connection to Player 2 and tries to reconnect to player2.
- Player 2 is looking for a new match, which he is doing with the matchmakerViewController.
- Player 2 suddenly joins the old match with Player 1, which he had left.

So my problem is that the matchmakerViewController let's players join old matches if they're reinvited. Is there a better way to handle this reconnection scenario so people won't get invited back to old matches?

Comment: @Cupcake.In my code it is happening that when 1player get disconnected other automatically disconnect from the game.Y it happen so?how  to avoid this disconnection of player 1 though player 2get diconnect

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an option to the player that still is connected, to either re-invite, or quit. You could also remove the matchmaking request to the player that left if the other player leaves.

Comment: My problems is the reinviting. Player 1 reinvites player 2 while player 2 is looking for a new game. This is a problem because player 2 will get reinvited to a game he left. I can't remove the matchmaking request if the other player leaves, because I don't know when he leaves. They're not connected at this point and cannot tell if the player leaves.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and prevent the reinvite from Player 1 on the same game if I detected Player 2 has used the quit function instead of timing out on a disconnect.

Comment: How would player 1 know that player 2 get disconnected?